# How to get price of my products show in snippet on google?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I use wp e-commerce plugin woocommerce to sell my products online.
I am trying to figure out how to get prices and reviews of my products shown in snippets on google. Is there a plugin that can help me with that?

*not sure if its relevant but as for now I use SEO by Yoast plugin to optimize my site.

Thank you in advance!

example below:

[image: See an exaple]
<sub>(source: [snag.gy](https://snag.gy/aYOv8.jpg))</sub>

Comment: Unfortunately, plugin recommendations are off-topic here - as are theird part products. Best to hit up the official WooCommerce support channels, or another community platform which caters to WooCommerce users.

Answer (score 0):

What you're after is called Rich Snippits which is structured data on your web page that tells Google specific information about your products. See https://developers.google.com/structured-data/rich-snippets/products

A plugin like http://authorhreview.com/plugins/wp-rich-snippets/ might be what you're looking for or you could modify your theme to add the right markup to make rich snippits work.